# Insert data in collection at Meteor's startup

Tags: javascript, json, meteor, startup

I would like to insert data at Meteor's startup. (And after from a JSON file)

At startup, I create a new account and I would like to insert data and link it to this account once this one created.

This is the code that creates the new account at startup:

```
if(!Meteor.users.findOne({emails: { $elemMatch: { address: "test@test.com"}}})){
    var id = Accounts.createUser({ email: "test@test.com", password: "1234", profile: { name: 'Test' } });
    Meteor.users.update({_id: id }, { $set: { admin: false }});
}
```

And after that, I need to insert data and link it to this account with its ID. (In different collections).

So I tried to do something like that, but obviously It didn't work:

```
UserData = new Mongo.Collection('user_data');

    if(!Meteor.users.findOne({emails: { $elemMatch: { address: "test@test.com"}}})){
        var id = Accounts.createUser({ email: "test@test.com", password: "1234", profile: { name: 'Test' } });
        Meteor.users.update({_id: id }, { $set: { admin: false }});
        UserData.insert({
            createdBy: id,
            firstname: "test",
            /* ... */
        });
    }
```

**EDIT**

Sorry for not have been clear.

The real issue is the :

```
UserData = new Mongo.Collection('user_data');
```

declaration is in another file, so I can't do like above.

As it's not in the same file, I tried to get the userId that got "test@test.com" as the email (the account's email created at startup). And once I got it, I want to use it in "createdBy: ID_HERE".

Comment: Can you add a description of what exactly it is that's not working?

Comment: Yes sorry, I've just made an edit :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, you'll want to check out [Structuring your application](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/structuringyourapp). You'll have to make the file with the definition load earlier, or the one with the `fixture` later.

Normally you have your collections inside *lib/* and your `fixture`s inside *server/fixtures.js*.

So if you put your insert code into *server/fixtures.js* it'll work.

Comment: Thanks! I'll change my application's tree, but could you tell me how I can get the userId linked the email "test@test.com" ?

Comment: This `Meteor.users.findOne({emails: { $elemMatch: { address: "test@test.com"}}})` returns a users `document`. So you can simply do `Meteor.users.findOne({emails: { $elemMatch: { address: "test@test.com"}}})._id` (server-side)

Comment: Now it's working, thank you very much ! It's weird, I've never heard about this "fixture" file in meteor.js...

Comment: I got the idea from [Discover Meteor](https://www.discovermeteor.com). Just to clarify; the file itself isn't special. Meteor loads `lib` directories first and then everything else including you `server` directory.

Comment: Yep I know but a lot of people use "fixture" as this file's name, it's probably become a small standard :)